# Android - Maintain recylerview selected item when view resizing

Tags: android

I have two FrameLayouts in an activity. The first one contains either a recylerview, or listview, the second one contains different controls depending on the situation.

I want to keep the selected item in the recylerview visible to the user when the controls are added to the second framelayout.

I use scrollToPosition on the recylerview layout manager when an item is selected, but this is called before the new controls are visible on screen so the selected item in the recylerview can be off screen.

Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working, for the most part. Using the below code in onCreateView. Hope this helps others

```
view.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom)
        {
            if ((bottom < oldBottom) && currentlyPlayingFile != null && currentlyPlayingFilePos != -1)
            {
                if (currentlyPlayingFilePos > (mFileData.length * 0.75))
                {
                    int moveAmount = oldBottom - bottom;
                    if (currentlyPlayingFilePos == (mFileData.length - 1))
                        moveAmount += 35;

                    mRecyclerView.scrollBy(0, moveAmount);
                }
                else
                {
                    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(currentlyPlayingFilePos);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```